# About Relation between Cyclic Group and Finite Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

For prime $p$, the collection of nonzero element of a finite field $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is cyclic group with multiplication,namely $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$.
And all cyclic group G with $n$ element is expressed as $\mathbb{Z}_n$ up to isomorphism.

Then, through both facts, Can I say that as follows?

- If $F$ is a finite field with $p^n$ element, then <$F^*, •$> is isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n-1}$.

If the answer is "**yes**", what is a isomorphism between <$\mathbb{Z}_p^*,•$> and< $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1},+$> when $n=1$ ??

- $F^*$ means all elements of the field $F$ except 0.
- • is a multiplication operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to you first question is yes. The non-zero elements of a finite field are a cyclic group for multiplication.

Regarding your second question, for $a$ a generating element of $F^*$, the isomorphism will be given by $a^n \mapsto n.1$.